# Characterization of the integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the book "Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis" by E.Mendelson the integers are characterized as an ordered integral domain where the positive elements are well ordered (p.152).

But in the book "Abstract Algebra: An Inquiry Based Approach" by J.K. Hodge the theorem 18.3 states "An ordered ring contains no zero divisors" (and, therefore any (commutatitve) ordered ring with identity is an integral domain).

Does it mean that in the Mendelson's book (in the characterization of the integers) we can replace "an ordered integral domain" with  "a commutative ordered ring with identity"?

Comment: Yes, but as you've stated, the hypotheses are equivalent... so you're not really weakening them.